# Cannot import Azure Storage Blob package even though it is installed

Tags: python, azure, pip, anaconda, azure-blob-storage

I want to write a script to upload files to Azure Blob Storage. I installed the Azure Storage Blob package following [this documentation](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/master/sdk/storage/azure-storage-blob/README.md) and then tried to run `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient` I got the error:

> No module named 'azure.storage'; 'azure' is not a package.

When I run `pip show azure-storage-blob` the package is in the expected place that is included in PATH.

The strange thing is that I can run `import azure` just fine but when I run `pip show azure` I get

> WARNING: Package(s) not found: azure

This doesnt work either: `from azure import BlobServiceClient`.

I am using Anaconda / Windows and I tried this with Python 3.6, 3.7 and 3.8 with the same results.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What are you using to run the code? IPython? A script in an IDE? A terminal in an IDE? It sounds like you have it installed in one environment and then you are executing the code in a different environment.

Comment: @EricTruett I am using Spyder to run the code and Anaconda Prompt to do the installations etc. I always make sure to switch environments as necessary though. I activate the environment using `conda activate` in Anaconda Prompt and open Spyder from the same environment (and check that it is the correct one on the bottom bar).

Comment: Try launching the anaconda prompt, then type ipython, then, in ipython, try ```from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient```. If you get an ImportError, then try ```!pip install azure-storage-blob``` and then try the import again.

Comment: @EricTruett Ok, I am very very confused right now. I tried `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient` and got no error. So I went to Spyder and just ran the import there. It worked. I did not change anything else but it is working now. No idea how but thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

This issue was solved by Eric Truett's comment, add it as the answer to close the question:

1. Try launching the anaconda prompt,
2. then type ipython,
3. then, in ipython, try `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient`.
4. If you get an ImportError, then try `!pip install azure-storage-blob` and then try the import again.

> I tried `from azure.storage.blob import BlobServiceClient` and got no
> error. So I went to Spyder and just ran the import there. It worked. I
> did not change anything else but it is working now.